# Wordpress as thesaurus/dictionnary: what approach?

Tags: taxonomy, tags, development-strategy, customization

I'm willing to develop a thesaurus/dictionary for the [Berber language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berber_languages). A website that allows comunity members to add new words/synonyms/antonyms..

1. How to  relate words (posts) to each other? by using tags? but with this approach, it's hard to keep organization when posts names/slugs are modified; then tags should be updated too.. consider the word "big" is already inserted as a post, then someone added the word "large" and related it to the word "big" by inserting a tag on it.. then comes a 3rd user and added the word "great"; this means all the posts with similar synonyms should be updated! **isn't it a bad approach going the tags way?**
2. Another issue is when I want to add antonyms; I cannot add them as tags since tags are reserved for synonyms! **so how to solve this complex structure keeping everything easy to maintain?**

**Update**

*Why taxonomies won't work?* Because taxonomies are meant for categorizing things that have different characterestics from each other; like in a movie database, you have a taxonomy for actors, one for diretors for example.. But since the words in a dictionary are "equal" they should be treated the same.. so I think more on using  [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)..

Thanks for any help and sorry for the long post :)

*PS; I don't want to use plugins to avoid dependence problemes.*

Comment: You won't get this done without plugin (or major amount of custom code) because so far WP does not provide functionality for complex relationships between posts.

Comment: Thanx Rarst, I'm a wordpress programmer (kind of intermediate) so custom code is okay as long as I don't use plugins :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create custom post types and custom taxonomy, taking the standard "Posts" out of the loop. You can then have two separate Taxonomies (Tag systems) for synonyms and antonyms.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

You can then use a plugin like Gravity Forms to have your users register for the site and submit their words, which can be turned into posts automatically.

http://www.gravityforms.com/

If this is all greek you may want a Wordpress dev for help. Let me know if you would need help and if this answer helps!

Comment: Thanx Tom, separating synonyms and antonyms into separate taxonomies (categories) is not logical; for example where to put "big" and "small"? they are both synonym and antonym at the same time for each other.

Comment: I use now custom fields to store coma separated id's of posts that are synonyms or antonyms,, thanks everybody :)